# THREE.js Wrap 3D object in a aquare grid

Tags: three.js, gridlines

I have looked and looked but have not come across anything close to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am using THREE.js and I have a 3D object, say a human skull. I want to wrap a square grid around its surface while maintaining the unit spacing of the grid lines. Like wire frame but all the line spacing is uniform and straight.

Goal is to have the user easily see the surface length of an object. Real world example. Draw a line from the front of a skull to the back over the top and measure the length of the line.

Any code example, or even a start on the process I could take to solve this problem using THREE.js.

Thanks

Comment: If I understand what you are describing, you can do that with a custom `ShaderMaterial` in three.js: Here is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/7wVu6/ There is plenty of room for improvement...

Answer (score 0):

you can compute Bounding Box on the object(skull) , and draw a cube using properties of Bounding Box .

> ```
> object.computeBoundingBox();
> // adding cube
> var centerX =   (object.boundingBox.max.x - object.boundingBox.min.x);
> var centerY =  (object.boundingBox.max.y - object.boundingBox.min.y);
> var centerZ =  (object.boundingBox.max.z - object.boundingBox.min.z);
> ```

```
var boundingBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(centerX, centerY, centerZ);
```

here is a sample fiddle for that : [Bounding box fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/WaCkS/4/)